# Let $f(x)$ be differentiable on for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and $|f'(x)|\le2$, for every $x$, and $f(9)=33$, $f(1)=17$. what is $f(5)=?$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I can't get how I can know stuff about $f(5)$ from the information that I got.
I tried to apply Lagrange: $\exists  c\space such\space  that\space 1<c<9 \space \space :f'(c)=\frac{f(9)-f(1)}{9-1} =2 $ 
 and I have no idea how to reach $f(5)$ from here.

any hints or tips or solutions will be appreciated!

Comment: You are on the right track. What can you say about $f(x)$ knowing that $f'(x) \leq 2$ and knowing that the difference between $f(1)$ and $f(9)$ is exactly $16$?

Comment: @Vydai Hi! from the answers I understood that the difference between $f(1)$ and $f(5)$ is 8, which means $f(5)=25$ which is in the middle, but I still don't really understand why does this happen? I can't seem to understand what the $|f'(x)\le2|$ tells me about the function. And thanks for the help :)

Comment: The $|f'(x) \leq 2|$ tells you that the gradient is not higher than $2$ or lower than $-2$ at any given point. There is exactly $8$ between $x = 1$ and $x = 9$. There is exactly $16$ between $f(1) = 17$ and $f(9) = 33$. From this we can deduce that $f(x)$ is a straight line between $x = 1$ and $x = 9$ with gradient $2$. That is the only way to get a difference of $16$ between $f(1)$ and $f(9)$. The gradient can't be higher due to $|f'(x) \leq 2|$. The gradient can't be lower due to the difference between $f(1)$ and $f(9)$ being exactly $16$.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you so much I think I get it now, what I thought about is if a function goes up and down between the two points f(1) and f(9), but the gradient being limited to 2 means that this will never happen hence it must be a a straight line, what I did by calculating $f'(c)=2$ was like for every point and not only one point? I couldn't infer that from the mean value theorem alone right?

Comment: I think Fred in the answers below is right. He basically used the MVT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have (mean value theorem)

$$| \frac{f(5)-f(1)}{4}|  \le 2.$$

Hence

$$ -8 \le f(5)-17 \le 8.$$

Therefore

$$f(5) \le 25.$$

In a similar way we get from $| \frac{f(9)-f(5)}{4}|  \le 2, $ that

$$f(5) \ge 25.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just to make sure if I got this right, so you basically took the derivative at 2 different points (Using the mean value theorem),  and applied it in $|f'(x)|\le2$ , and got that $f(5)$ must be 25 for this to be true. did I understand it in a good way?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: $$f(5) = \frac{f(1)+f(9)}{2} = \frac{17 + 33}{2} = 25.$$
Justification: Suppose not.  $f(5) = 25 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  Invoke MVT: $\exists c_1 \in (1,5): f'(c_1) = \frac{f(5)-f(1)}{5-1} = \frac{25+\epsilon-17}{4} > 2$, contradicting the condition that $|f'(x)| \le 2$ for all $x$ in the domain.
Exercise: Repeat this type of argument for $f$ on $(5,9)$.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer! But I really didn't understand why did you divide by 2 while calculating $f(5)$ , how did you know that it must be in the middle?

Comment: Before I write my answer, I already had a picture of a line passing through the two given points in my mind.  In higher dimensions, differentiation means best local linear approximation.

Answer (score 0):

- $g(x):=f(x)-2x$;
- $g(9)=g(1)=15$
- $g'(x)=f'(x)-2 \le 0$ meaning $g(x)$ is monotone non-increasing.

Therefore $g$ is constant between $1$ and $9$, $f(5)=g(5)+10=25$.